# Приложение находится в режиме приостановки выполнения

Tags: c#

Ошибка: Приложение перешло в состояние останова, но в данный момент не выполняется код, который поддерживается выбранным модулем отладки (например, выполняется только машинный код).
Просто внезапно РАБОЧИЙ код стал НЕ РАБОЧИМ.

В чем может быть проблема?
Отбэкапил даже тот код, который работал, но он теперь тоже не запускается!

Answer (score 1):

Как я понимаю, вы нажимаете Pause во время дебага.

Когда вы это делаете, то программа может находится в неуправляемом блоке. Что бы из него выйти нужно нажать на кнопку F11 и тогда вы вернетесь в свой код и сможете отлаживать по шагам.